# What's the hand stacking gesture called?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is it called, the gesture whereby a team stack their hands on top of each other's with their palms face-down, then swing their arms quickly backwards, and go "Yeah!" or something, before they enthusiastically engage in some sort of teamwork activity?

Comment: Do you have a term for this in your native language? Hand-stack (as mentioned by Ricky) has an entry in tvtropes.org. It also has good results in a Google image search. I didn't see any definitions for "hand huddle", but it has better Google image results, and it's alliterative... I think.

Comment: I also think *huddle* is going to clue people into what sort of hand stacking is going on.  Also potentially *circle up*.

Answer (score 2):

Oddly enough, it is actually called a "***hand-stack***."

According to this link, anyway:

[hand-stack](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TeamHandStack)

Comment: I got that as one of the results Googling the gesture but it seemed too on the nose, and I couldn't find an authoritative source for it.

Comment: I don't know. You could look up the Latin words for "hand" and "stack" and make up a term: why not?

Comment: The more informal an expression is, the longer it takes to achieve any significant level of authoritativeness. Language description can very snobby, so it is is a good idea to respect the users actually using the term as being the authorities.

Comment: @Ricky What I Googled was "hand stacking gesture", sir. Being overtly facetious doesn't help. In case you didn't know, I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Hm. MW says *hand stack* is "a small pile of hay".

Comment: @Vun-HughVaw: I was only half-joking. All formal terms are made up, one way or another. Why not make one?

Comment: @michael.hor257k: MW isn't Scripture, you know.